# Difference between implementation of functional interface, used along with streams

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to understand the working of filtering stream here. 
Below are two approaches to filter out duplicates from `List` of `String`s.
(I dont want to use distinct keyword for demonstrative purposes)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(){{add("abc");add("abc");add("abcd");}};
List<String> list1 = list.parallelStream().filter(e->{
                                           Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
                                           return seen.add(e.getLastName());
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Above approach doesn't seem to work as new instance of `Set` is being created each time.

```
List<String> list2  =    
list.parallelStream().filter(distincyByKey(e>e.getLastName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    public static <T> Predicate<T> distincyByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Set<Object> seen =  ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        System.out.println("testttttttttttt");
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
```

This approach seems to working. Not sure what's the difference between approach 1 & 2. I see that `distincyByKey` is a static method, but how does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet creates a new `Set` instance every time the lambda expression body is executed, which means once for each element of the `Stream`. Therefore, each time the filter is applied on an element of the `Stream`, it adds the element to a different `Set` instance, so it fails to filter out duplicates.

In your second snippet, the `Set` instance is created once, when the `distincyByKey()` is executed. When the filter is evaluated on each element of the `Stream`, the lambda body executed is just `seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t)`, and it's always executed for the same `Set` instance.

You can achieve the same behavior without the `static` method by either creating the `Set` instance outside the Stream pipeline, or by using a method reference:

```
Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
List<String> list1 = 
    list.parallelStream().filter(e-> seen.add(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<String> list1 = 
    list.parallelStream().filter(ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()::add).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: I removed the `getLastName()` method call from the code, since your `Stream` is a `Stream<String>`, and `String`s don't have a `getLastName()` method. I guess you mixed up some code snippets.

Comment: Thanks much. Could you please tell me if its specified in functionality of lambda or streams?

Comment: @user2296988 I'm not sure what exactly you are expecting to see specified. The important thing to understand is when each statement of your code gets executed. The argument passed to `filter()` is evaluated once, when the `Stream` is created. The `test()` method of the `Predicate` passed to `filter()` is executed for each element of your `Stream`. Once you figure out which part of your code becomes the implementation of that `test()` method in each snippet, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So, usually a lambda should have only parameters and a return statement(or void). If it has any instance variable in body implementation, it would also be considered as a parameter.Thanks

Comment: could you pls explain if there is any way to user you second apporach for member variables. Example, I am passing a variable for a class into predicate.

Comment: @user2296988 I'll have to see the actual example code. It's not clear enough from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is exactly about your `Set` objects.

In the first code snippet, `seen` is created by the predicate. The predicate is called for each element. This means that each time the predicate is called, a set instance is created. In the second, the set is created by `distincyByKey()`, which runs only once when the stream is being created.

The predicate returned by `distincyByKey` holds a reference to that one set, and each time it runs, it uses the same instance. If you were to make the second code run like the first one, the method would look like this:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distincyByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    return t -> {
        Set<Object> seen =  ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
}
```

This version would be as broken as your first implementation.

Comment: Oh wow, never knew you can write return statements that way. Good post!